# Insert href into a row

Tags: datatables

I'm trying to make my last row a link using a variable I'm getting from ajax.

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            paging: false,
            "ajax": "includes/payroll.php",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "className": 'details-control',
                    "orderable": false,
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": ''
                },
                {"data": "empNum"},
                {"data": "empName"},
                {"data": "appFlag"},
                {"data": "unitRate"},
                {"data": "salary"},
                {"data": "hourly"},
                {



                    "defaultContent": '<?php echo '<a href=EmployeeInfo.php?empNum='.'data[0]'.'>Info</a>';?>'
                }

            ],
            "order": [[1, 'asc']]
        });
```

I need to use the empNum in the link for the php but I don't know how to get the empNum element into my php echo. I've tried mData and mRender, but it didn't work because I don't think I'm using them correctly.

```
Array
(
[data] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [empNum] => 1
            [empName] => SMITH, MARK E.           
            [unitRate] => 0
            [salary] => 3282.84
            [hourly] => 0
            [appFlag] =>  
            [app1] => K002 1       
            [app2] =>              
            [app3] =>              
            [app4] =>              
            [app5] =>              
            [uni1] => .00
            [uni2] => .00
            [uni3] => .00
            [uni4] => .00
            [uni5] => .00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [empNum] => 2
            [empName] => SMITH, BRYANT J.        
            [unitRate] => 0
            [salary] => 0
            [hourly] => 800
            [appFlag] =>  
            [app1] => 1E2          
            [app2] =>              
            [app3] =>              
            [app4] =>              
            [app5] =>              
            [uni1] => .00
            [uni2] => .00
            [uni3] => .00
            [uni4] => .00
            [uni5] => .00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [empNum] => 4
            [empName] => SMITH, JENNIFER L   
            [unitRate] => 0
            [salary] => 1708.5
            [hourly] => 0
            [appFlag] =>  
            [app1] => 1A1          
            [app2] =>              
            [app3] =>              
            [app4] =>              
            [app5] =>              
            [uni1] => .00
            [uni2] => .00
            [uni3] => .00
            [uni4] => .00
            [uni5] => .00
        )
```

Here is the payroll.php page

```
<?php

include_once("dbconnect.php");
$types = array();
$connect = TRUE;
$dbconn = dbconnect($connect);

if ($dbconn) {
$sql = 'select dec(substr(hex(substr(f00001,1,3)),1,5),5,0),                 
              cast(substr(f00001,7,25) as char(25) ccsid 37),                    
              int(dec(substr(hex(substr(f00001,135,3)),1,5),5,0)),                    
              double(dec((dec(substr(hex(substr(f00001,142,4)),1,7),7,0)/100),7,2)),   
              double(dec(substr(hex(substr(f00001,146,3)),1,5),5,0)),                   
              cast(substr(f00001,679,1) as char(1) ccsid 37),                  
              cast(substr(f00001,1421,13) as char(13) ccsid 37),                   
              cast(substr(f00001,1434,13) as char(13) ccsid 37),                   
              cast(substr(f00001,1447,13) as char(13) ccsid 37),                   
              cast(substr(f00001,1460,13) as char(13) ccsid 37),                   
              cast(substr(f00001,1473,13) as char(13) ccsid 37),                    
              dec((dec(substr(hex(substr(f00001,1486,4)),1,7),7,0)/100),7,2),       
              dec((dec(substr(hex(substr(f00001,1490,4)),1,7),7,0)/100),7,2),       
              dec((dec(substr(hex(substr(f00001,1494,4)),1,7),7,0)/100),7,2),       
              dec((dec(substr(hex(substr(f00001,1498,4)),1,7),7,0)/100),7,2),       
              dec((dec(substr(hex(substr(f00001,1502,4)),1,7),7,0)/100),7,2)     
               from qs36f."PR.MST"
               where  dec(substr(hex(substr(f00001,5,2)),1,3),3,0) <>0';
$stmt = db2_prepare($dbconn, $sql);
if ($stmt) {
    $result = db2_execute($stmt);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "execute errormsg: " . db2_stmt_errormsg($stmt);
    }

    while ($row = db2_fetch_array($stmt)) {

        $load['data'][] = array(
            'empNum' => $row[0],
            'empName' => $row[1],
            'unitRate' => $row[2],
            'salary' => $row[3],
            'hourly' => $row[4],
            'appFlag' => $row[5],
            'app1' => $row[6],
            'app2' => $row[7],
            'app3' => $row[8],
            'app4' => $row[9],
            'app5' => $row[10],
            'uni1' => $row[11],
            'uni2' => $row[12],
            'uni3' => $row[13],
            'uni4' => $row[14],
            'uni5' => $row[15]
        );
    }
} else {
    echo "execute errormsg: " . db2_stmt_errormsg($stmt);
}
db2_close($dbconn);
} else {
echo "faild " . db2_conn_errormsg();
}


$json = json_encode($load);
echo $json;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`render` is what you need. `defaultContent` has no knowledge of the data so you wouldn't be able to assign a variable. You don't need to use the PHP tags either.

```
{
    "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
        return '<a href= \'EmployeeInfo.php?empNum=' + full.empNum +  '\'>Info</a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this. My table disappeared.

Comment: That made me laugh! Sorry, there _were_ quite a few typo's in that answer! Fixed now.

Comment: I laughed when I read your post. So, I go the table back. Now I get this error: DataTables warning: table id=example - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1. And my table is forever loading.

Comment: If you replace that return line with `return '';` does it work? (just checking that the error is on that line)

Comment: Yup. I've even added the link and it redirected, but I need it to pass that empNum. So here I am.

Comment: I'll get back to this tomorrow if it's not fixed in the meantime

Comment: Hey markpsmith, I'm an idiot. I changed the payroll page to see the output and didn't echo my json back out. After I fixed that your code worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your use of single and double quotes is incorrect. Try this:

```
<?php echo '<a href= " EmployeeInfo.php?empNum=' . data[0] . ' ">Info</a>'; ?>
```

Comment: i tried that and get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' . That is where the data[0] is.

Comment: What is data[0]? I don't see a data array in your code, but I see a columns array with objects inside that have properties of data.

I think what you're looking for is Columns[1].data

Comment: Ah yes, I don't understand that either. I took this example straight from the datatables web site and it works. I'm use to returning an array and then parsing it. So with this code I've been trying to figure out where the array is. I changed it to Columns[1].data and get the same error.

Comment: I think I might have misguided you because I misinterpreted what you were doing, but with what you had originally...you were still not using single and double quotes correctly.

Where is the data array at? Is that on the payroll page and are you making that array the response when you make the ajax call?